# What is the reverse key of 'C-i' in vim insert mode?

Tags: vim

In vim's insert mode, 'C-t' and 'C-d' can insert or delete Tab/4whitespace **from the beginning of current line** and:

'C-i' can insert Tab/4whitespace **from current cursor**.

BUT, how can we **delete** 4 whitespace from current cursor? What is the reverse operation of 'C-i' ?

Comment: Notice that: 'C-i' or Tab not only insert 4 whitespace. They insert space to the column exactly a multiple of 4. For example, our cursor at column 13 and we use 'C-i', it insert 3 whitespace to column 16. if we use 'C-i' again, it insert 4 whitespace to column 20.

Comment: And , Im looking for a key to get a reverse: if we are at column 19, we should delete 3 whitespace to column 16.

Comment: `<C-I>` **is** `<Tab>`. If you also have `setl expandtab` then Vim expands newly entered tab(s) into spaces. There shouldn't be any "reverse operation" except `u` or such.

Comment: It is conceivable that one wants to delete space back to the previous tab position, hence you perhaps shouldn't say _shouldn't be_, but rather **isn't**.

Comment: @Matt When we write code like `#define xxx   1` `#define xxxxx 2` , always we need to align the 1 and 2, the Tab can easily do that. But, if we pressed Tab one more time, we need a lot of operations to delete these redundant whitespaces. That's why i'm looking for a key to do the reverse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no built-in command that does what you want.

One way to do something like it "manually" is:

```
<C-c>ciw
```

- `<C-c>` to leave insert mode without triggering autocommands, leaving the cursor on the last `<Space>`,
- `ciw` to cut the sequence of `<Spaces>`, which Vim treats as a "word", and enter insert mode.

Now that we have a working macro, it is trivial to map to something convenient:

```
inoremap <key> <C-c>ciw
```

And we can make it even better by preventing it from polluting registers with useless     s:

```
inoremap <key> <C-c>"_ciw
```

Note that this mapping works for any sequence of `<Tab>`s and/or `<Space>`s as well.

---

Now, as noted by @Eineki, the mapping above is not a true inverse `<C-i>` because it deletes all the contiguous whitespace before the cursor, regardless of tabulations.

If you only pressed `<C-i>` once, then that mappings will effectively act as an inverse `<C-i>`, but if you have more than a `&shiftwidth` of `<Space>`s, the whole sequence will be deleted, which is not what a true inverse `<C-i>` would do.

A true inverse `<C-i>` would delete `<Space>`s up to the previous tabulation, which sounds a tad less trivial.

Comment: To be noted: if you have more than 4 spaces in a row (maybe two <C-i>?)  it will erase all of them. When in a hurry, you can resort to <C-u> to simply undo the last command?

Comment: @Eineki you are correct. I will put a note about it.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my suggestion for the *a tad less trivial* *true inverse* (as defined by romainl) of <kbd>TAB</kbd>:

```
function! BAT()
        while getline(".")[col(".")-2] =~ "\\s"
                normal X
                if virtcol(".")%&tabstop == 1
                        break
                endif
        endwhile
endfunction
imap <S-Tab> <C-O>:call BAT()<CR>
```

Comment: Wooow~! It really works, many thanks. But I'm really upset that there is not an original key or keys to do this.

Comment: Juuuuuust a tad.

Comment: @JianfengWang if this answer works for you, please mark it as "accepted".

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<C-o>4dh` (or `<C-o>4d<Left>` if you prefer arrows) to delete 4 characters to the left of the current insert position.

Note: `<C-o>` allows you to temporarily use normal-mode commands from insert-mode.